# tkSnack not working properly

Tags: python, macos, architecture, module, python-2.7

I'm using Python 2.7 and I'm trying to use tkSnack but I don't really get it.

I installed it but when I do initializeSnack(), it gives me: /Library/Tcl/snack2.2/libsnack.dylib: mach-o, but wrong architecture

I tried searching it for a long time but none of them gave me a clear answer what I should do. 
Does anyone know what I need to do?

I'm using Mac OS X Lion with Python 2.7 by the way.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe [this](http://mail.python.org/pipermail/tkinter-discuss/2008-June/001465.html) and the following reply also fits your case.
The problem seems to be related with an out-of-date version of Tcl/Tk.

Comment: Yeah I read that but I am using the most up-to-date version of Tcl/Tk, 8.5. On tkSnack's website it looked like I need to have 8.4 but on the Python's website it said it's for 32bit only. I'm a noob in this area so I might just not know :(